# G Suite Marketplace SDK change visibility from My Domain to Public?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I've enabled a G Suite Marketplace SDK but initially I set the Visibility to "My Domain" so I could test in isolation on my domain.  Now I want to set it to Public but that setting is disabled.

Warning: Once you select and save a visibility setting, you cannot change it later. (https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk)

However I can't even disable/delete that API configuration and recreate it, so I can set it to public.

Is there any way to change this GSuite Marketplace API configuration to Public? (without having to tear down the entire Google Project and all it's API configurations and start over... seems there should be a better way)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to access your [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and click the edit part of your item. You can check there if you can set the visibility option of your item.

I think once you change it, it will undergo a manual review and you need to wait some time to be approve.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  That is the Chrome store dashboard and I do have an app in there which I can toggle the visibility on, however this is in the [Cloud Platform Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/) where I have configured the G Suite Marketplace SDK.  I set the visibility to "My domain" (for testing) and now it won't let me change to Public, which the doc confirms.   What I'm most surprised about is that I can't delete that configuration and recreate it as Public.  It seems my only option is to create an entirely new Project, which means resetting all keys, ids, etc.

Comment: I have the same problem where I can't change this in the Cloud Platform Dashboard. Disabling the Marketplace API and re-enabling maintains the visibility setting. Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: @Lucas I'm encountering the same problem. Have you resolved it already?

Comment: @martijn I contacted Google support and confirmed that the only way to resolve this is to create an entirely new app and choose Public the first time you save it. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Google support and confirmed that the only way to resolve this is to create an entirely new app and choose Public the first time you save it. I hope that helps.

Comment: That helps. Google suck sometimes. Why not implement a delete button?

Comment: Do you mean creating a whole GCP project? Or how do you delete "the app"? Thanks

Comment: @darkade I do mean creating a whole new project with a new Client ID, etc. 
It's possible they've changed it within the last year but that was my experience a little less than a year ago.

Comment: that is insane. sheesh. Gotta love Google