# How to change visibility of G Suite Marketplace app?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We published an application in "My Domain" visibility to test it, but now want to switch it to become publicly available. However, it appears Google doesn't allow the visibility to be changed once it's been set. What is the right approach to handle this case?

Unpublishing the app or disabling then re-enabling the G Suite Marketplace SDK don't seem to help, and it's not apparent how to "wipe" the application and start a brand new one.

Comment: have you resolved this already? I'm also stuck here..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716134/g-suite-marketplace-sdk-change-visibility-from-my-domain-to-public#comment103925084_53728727) by @Lucas, the only way to resolve this is to create an entirely new [GCP project](https://console.cloud.google.com/).