# I need to change my App Visibility to Public with already accepted scopes - but it can't be changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

We are now building a Google Add-on for our project, but when configuring the visibility in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK I mistakenly selected "Private" when I meant to select "Public". The UI says I cannot change it to Public.

I see in [other StackOverflow pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716134/g-suite-marketplace-sdk-change-visibility-from-my-domain-to-public) that other developers have tried to change it, but the only option is to create a new GCP project.

We are building a Google Workspace Add-on to complement our API integration, however the misconfiguration of "Private" instead of "Public" in the App Visibility (and its impossibility to be reverted) is causing us some concern.

This situation is a bit worrying for our team since we have already 500+ signed-in users in the current project. If indeed we need to create a new project, that means re-onboarding them into a new project, which is a nightmare to manage.

We have the CASA-certified app in this project (restricted scopes), **how are the approved scopes going to work across projects?** Do I have to create a whole new project and start CASA all over again?

I tried disabling the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK API, but that doesn't remove the actual configuration.